# Scanner calling nextLine() issues NoSuchLineException

Tags: java

I am trying to make a game that asks for the user's name, is skeptical of the name, and then asks the user three questions, here is my code so far with two out of 3 questions on it.

```
private static final Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello user! what is your name? ");
    String Name = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Really? " + Name + " is too weird to be a real name.");
    confirmation();
    Mascot();
    Fence();
    System.out.println("Thank you for playing the demo");

    console.close(); 
}

public static void confirmation() {
    
    System.out.print("is that REALLY your name? (type Y/N) ");
    String yN = console.nextLine();
    String a = yN;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(a);
    if (scanner.hasNext("Y")) {
        System.out.println("I still dont belive you, so you will have to answer 3 riddles before you can continue to the game");
    } else{
        calledIt();
    }
    scanner.close();
     
}

public static void calledIt() {
    
    System.out.println("I knew it!");
    System.out.print("whats your real name? ");
    String realName =console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("" + realName + "sounds like a real name, but you lied the first time so you will need to answer riddles 3 to continue to the game");
    
}

public static void Mascot() {
    
    System.out.println("what Is our school mascot?");
    String b = console.nextLine();
    if (b.toLowerCase().contains("tiger")){
        System.out.println("Good, next riddle.");

    } else{
        System.out.println("You have failed");
    }
    
}
public static void Fence() {
    System.out.println("What runs around the whole yard without moving?");
    String c = console.nextLine();
    if (c.toLowerCase().contains("fence")){
        System.out.println("Good, next riddle.");

    } else{
        System.out.println("You have failed");
    }
    
}
```

}

This is the current output ( with a random name)

```
Hello user! what is your name? 
bob
Really? bob is too weird to be a real name.
is that REALLY your name? (type Y/N) Y
I still dont belive you, so you will have to answer 3 riddles before you can continue to the game
what Is our school mascot?
bob
You have failed
What runs around the whole yard without moving?
```

I want it to accept Y or y as the "yes input in confirmation().
If any of the questions are answered incorrectly the program needs to stop and not continue to the next question. since I answered the first question with bob it should say you have failed then stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating many number of Scanner instances, have one in place to read from System.in, and close it when all work is done.

```
private static final Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello user! what is your name? ");
    String Name = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Really? " + Name + " is too weird to be a real name.");
    confirmation();
    Mascot();
    System.out.println("Thank you for playing the demo");

    console.close(); 
}

public static void confirmation() {
    
    System.out.print("is that REALLY your name? (type Y/N) ");
    String yN = console.nextLine();
    String a = yN;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(a);
    if (scanner.hasNext("Y")) {
        System.out.println("I still dont belive you, so you will have to answer 3 riddles before you can continue to the game");
    } else{
        calledIt();
    }
    scanner.close();
     
}

public static void calledIt() {
    
    System.out.println("I knew it!");
    System.out.print("whats your real name? ");
    String realName =console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("" + realName + "sounds like a real name, but you lied the first time so you will need to answer riddles 3 to continue to the game");
    
}

public static void Mascot() {
    
    System.out.println("what Is our school mascot?");
    String b = console.nextLine();
    if (b.toLowerCase().contains("tiger")){
        System.out.println("Good, next riddle.");

    } else{
        System.out.println("You have failed");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: how do i make it stop the program after stating you have failed

Answer (score 0):

Because you have terminated `System.in` stream by calling `scanner.close()` in `confirmation()` method, you can not read the stream anymore, so calling `String realName =console.nextLine();` will issue the exception.

**Solution:** Remove `scanner.close()` calls in your code.

Comment: @MentalOverload, Ok. You dont need to close scanner's System.in stream, Java virtual Machine will take care of it for you when your program closes.